# Agregar CheckBox en un ListView

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms

Quisiera agregar una columna que contenga un `CheckBox` con la siguiente información:

- Seguro Asistencia
- Seguro Desgravamen
- Columna que contenga `CheckBox`

Como la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo avanzando en código:

```
Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.ListView1.View = View.Details
    Me.ListView1.GridLines = True
    ListView1.HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.Nonclickable
    Dim columnHeader1 As New ColumnHeader
    With columnHeader1
        .Text = "Numero de Credito"
        .TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left
        .Width = 146
    End With
    Dim columnHeader2 As New ColumnHeader
    With columnHeader2
        .Text = "Numero Cuota"
        .TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center
        .Width = 142
    End With
    Dim columnHeader3 As New ColumnHeader
    With columnHeader3
        .Text = "Ultima Cuota"
        .TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center
        .Width = 142
    End With

    conn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=BASE_DATOS;User ID=USUARIO;Password=CONTRASENA")
    Dim strQ As String = String.Empty
    strQ = "select top 2 Descripcion from credito..Rubro WHERE IdRubro NOT IN (41,42,44,45,1056,1057,1058,48,43) "
    cmd = New SqlCommand(strQ, conn)
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    ds = New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "Rubros")
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim j As Integer = 0
    ' adding the columns in ListView
    For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        'For j = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
        Dim LSet = Me.ListView1.Columns.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(j).ToString())

        LSet.Width = 218
    Next
    'Now adding the Items in Listview
    For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        For j = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
            itemcoll(j) = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(j).ToString()
        Next

        Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(itemcoll)
        Me.ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: deberías tener cuidado con la `información sensible` que muestras en el código de tu pregunta, en este caso de tu cadena de conexión.

Comment: Muchas Gracias @Davlio no me había percatado mil gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mira, para poder agregar una columna que contenga checkboxs, solamente "basta" con escribir esta linea de codigo:

```
ListView1.CheckBoxes = True
```

Digo, "basta", entre comillas ya que generalmente no suele arrojar buenos resultados solamente escribiendo esta linea. Muchas veces queremos controlar la posicion de esa columna y podemos lograrlo moviendo su **indice**.

He preparado este pequeño ejemplo para ti, he creado una pequeña ventana con un control ListView que tiene 3 columnas: Cedula, Nombre Completo y Pagado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo para esto es el siguiente:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim ced(3) As String
    Dim nombres(3) As String
    ced(0) = "8-754-1234"
    ced(1) = "3-736-945"
    ced(2) = "4-342-1234"
    nombres(0) = "Kristian Bale"
    nombres(1) = "Natasha Williams"
    nombres(2) = "Frederick Jhonson"
    ListView1.View = View.Details
    ListView1.CheckBoxes = True

    ListView1.Columns.Add("Pagado", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Cedula", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Nombre completo", 250, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
    ListView1.Columns(0).DisplayIndex = ListView1.Columns.Count - 1

    For i As Integer = 0 To 2 Step 1
        Dim item As New ListViewItem
        item.SubItems.Add(ced(i))
        item.SubItems.Add(nombres(i))
        ListView1.Items.Add(item)
    Next
End Sub
```

Como puedes apreciar, he creado dos arreglos para cargar las 2 columnas (Cedula y Nombre completo) de items. Nota como he usado la linea de codigo de arriba.

Ahora, debajo de eso le añadi las columnas con su respectiva etiqueta, alineacion y ancho... creo que vas a notar esta linea de aqui abajo:

```
ListView1.Columns(0).DisplayIndex = ListView1.Columns.Count - 1
```

Con esta linea, hago que la columna con indice 0 (osea, la primera columna que agregue, que en este caso es **Pagado**) sea la que ocupe **la ultima posicion de la tabla**.

Como paso final, cargue los diferentes valores a las columnas asignadas. Trabajar con ListView al inicio suele ser un poco tedioso y complicado (especialmente para los nuevos), pero ya te vas acostumbrando con el tiempo.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 2 Step 1
    Dim item As New ListViewItem
    item.SubItems.Add(ced(i)) 'Cargando registro a la columna Cedula'
    item.SubItems.Add(nombres(i)) 'Cargando registro a la columna Nombre completo'
    ListView1.Items.Add(item) 'añadiendo ListViewItem al ListView'
Next
```

Por lo que entiendo de tu pregunta... quieres tambien que el checkbox tenga una **etiqueta a su lado**, en este ejemplo lo lograriamos de la siguiente manera:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim ced(3) As String
    Dim nombres(3) As String
    Dim checkBox(3) As String
    ced(0) = "8-754-1234"
    ced(1) = "3-736-945"
    ced(2) = "4-342-1234"
    nombres(0) = "Kristian Bale"
    nombres(1) = "Natasha Williams"
    nombres(2) = "Frederick Jhonson"
    checkBox(0) = "A"
    checkBox(1) = "B"
    checkBox(2) = "C"
    ListView1.View = View.Details
    ListView1.CheckBoxes = True

    ListView1.Columns.Add("Pagado", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Cedula", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Nombre completo", 250, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
    ListView1.Columns(0).DisplayIndex = ListView1.Columns.Count - 1

    For i As Integer = 0 To 2 Step 1
        Dim item As New ListViewItem(checkBox(i))'Cargando etiquetas a los checkboxs'
        item.SubItems.Add(ced(i))
        item.SubItems.Add(nombres(i))
        ListView1.Items.Add(item)
    Next
End Sub
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**Recordemos**

```
Dim item as new ListViewItem("Esta linea representa tu primera columna")
item.Subitem.Add("Esta linea representa tu segunda columna")
item.Subitem.Add("Esta linea representa tu tercera columna")
item.Subitem.add("Esta linea representa tu cuarta columna")
......
......
......
y asi sucesivamente.
```

Espero que esta respuesta te sirva de guia :)

Comment: Mil gracias de verdad me ayudo de mucho.Una consulta como seria si haría los campos se llenen con sql server

Comment: Eso es otra pregunta aparte... ya ahi entraria consultas junto a ciclos for... personalmente me agrada irme al for each. @Pierro

Comment: muchas gracias si realice una pregunta si me podrias ayudar por favor